# Pandas: Replace duplicates by their mean values in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, duplicates, aggregate

I have been working with a dataframe in Pandas that contains duplicate entries along with non-duplicates in a column. The dataframe looks something like this:

```
    country_name  values  category
0   country_1     10       a
1   country_2     20       b
2   country_1     50       a
3   country_2     10       b
4   country_3     100      c
5   country_4     10       d
```

I want to write something that converts(replaces) duplicates with their mean values in my dataframe. An ideal output would be something similar to the following:

```
    country_name  values    category
0   country_1      30        a
1   country_2      15        b
2   country_3      100       c
3   country_4      10        d
```

I have been struggling with this for a while so I would appreciate any help. I have forgotten to add category column. The problem with `groupby()` method as you now when you call `mean()` it does  not return `category` column back. My solution was to take numerical columns and the column that has duplicates together apply `groupby().mean()` then concatenate back to the categorical columns. So I am looking for a solution shorten than what I have done.
My method get tedious when you are dealing with many categorical columns.

Answer (score 5):

You can use df.groupby():

```
df.groupby('country_name').mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I fixed my question. So the real issue is the categorical columns when you apply `groupby()` method for removing duplicates. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @cyber-math in this case, the code below works: `df.groupby('country_name').agg({'values': 'mean', 'category': lambda x: pd.unique(x)}).reset_index()`

Comment: ah, but it will not work when you have more complicated categorical column

Comment: one more attempt: `df[~df.duplicated(subset=['country_name', 'category'])].groupby('country_name').transform('mean').join(df[['country_name', 'category']][~df.duplicated(subset=['country_name', 'category'])])`